# asp.net mvc 5 actionlink 404 error with Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-areas

**I have an index.cshtml inside a path like *TeacherArea/Home/Index* where I have this following actionlink: **

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTeachers", "Home", new { Area = "TeacherArea", id = item.id }, new { })
```

**The purpose is to edit simple table row data.**
**My Home Controller looks like this:**

```
namespace DemoProject2MVC.Areas.TeacherArea.Controllers
 [RouteArea("TeacherArea")]
        [RoutePrefix("TeacherArea/Home")]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            return view();
        }

    [Route("EditTeachers")]
            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {           
                    MyDBContext stn = new MyDBContext();
                    Teacher tchr = stn.Teacher.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                return View(tchr);      
        }
```

** I also have set namespace in "TeacherAreaAreaRegistration" of the controller class present inside the area like the following:**

```
 public class TeacherAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "TeacherArea";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "TeacherArea_default",
                "TeacherArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "DemoProject2MVC.Areas.TeacherArea.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

**I also have my global.asax like this:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            DataAccessLayer.StartUpClass.Start();
        }
```

**My issue is:
The index action method is calling fine within this mentioned area. But the actionlink to call Edit Action method is throwing 404.**

> https://localhost:44336/TeacherArea/Home/EditTeachers/7

Comment: what does the URL generated by the ActionLink look like?

Comment: Try using "EditTeachers" as the action name. Review this examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit rusty on MVC, but I think that if you want to mix attribute-based area declarations/routing with area/route registration in startup you need to make sure you are registering stuff in the proper order.

Another thing I noticed was that you're never calling `RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your startup -- is that intentional?

> If you are using both Areas with route attributes, and areas with convention based routes (set by an AreaRegistration class), then you need to make sure that area registration happen after MVC attribute routes are configured, however before the default convention-based route is set. The reason is that route registration should be ordered from the most specific (attributes) through more general (area registration) to the mist generic (the default route) to avoid generic routes from “hiding” more specific routes by matching incoming requests too early in the pipeline.

[MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reverting back. I have actually declared MapMvcAttributeRoutes  in RegisterRoute class at AppStart. I am only using attribute routing in my entire solution. I even have tried to reorder the AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() at global asax after solution level routing are called but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Ajax approach..

```
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<URL you want>',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: id}),
            success: function (data) { 
                     ...
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     ...
            }
        });
```

And your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditTeachers(int Id)
            {           
                    MyDBContext stn = new MyDBContext();
                    Teacher tchr = stn.Teacher.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                return Json(tchr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
        }
```

It might be easier to debug because you can see the where the Ajax request is going from this by inspecting the network.

Hope it helps